# Check if bluetooth devices are currently pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have two bluetooth devices : phone and a pos printer(remote device) ,so I want to check the pairing state between them(if they are pairing(phone's bluetooth is on, pos printer's bluetooth is on,and they are connecting to each other), i will send some commands to printer to print out something).

But I don't know how to check if they are **connecting** or not .
There is a few something that i tried:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
```

Even if pos printer's bluetooth is off , I still get pos printer's bluetooth information (like `device.getBondState()` , `bluetoothClass.getDeviceClass`, `device.getName()` )

I tried to check the state with `BroadcastReceiver`but it showed nothing :

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        final BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra( BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE );

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equalsIgnoreCase( action ) )   {
            Log.d(CTAG, "We are now connected to " + device.getName() );
            if (!connectedDevices.contains(device))
                connectedDevices.add(device);
        }

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equalsIgnoreCase( action ) )    {
            Log.d(CTAG, "We have just disconnected from " + device.getName() );
            connectedDevices.remove(device);
        }
    }
```

How can i achieve this ? Any ideas will be appreciated.